# How can I sort values in a table based on a column from another table and a column from the original table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, join

I'm having difficulty figuring out a query that will sort my table by a column from another table and also sort it by column from the table itself.

Suppose I have two tables, `TableA(id, name, b_id)` and `TableB(id, name)`. I'm trying to create a query such that I can output rows in `TableA` ordered by `TableB.name` and `TableA.name`.

For example:

```
TableA
------
1 A4 11
2 A2 12
3 A3 13
4 A1 11

TableB
------
11 B1
12 B2
13 B3

Expected Output
---------------
4 A1 11
1 A4 11
2 A2 12
3 A3 13
```

To get rows ordered by `TableB.name`, the following worked:

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE b_id IN (SELECT id FROM TableB);`

```
(Wrong) Output
--------------
1 A4 11
4 A1 11
2 A2 12
3 A3 13
```

And to get rows order by `TableA.name`, the following worked:

`SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY name;`

```
(Wrong) Output
--------------
4 A1 11
2 A2 12
3 A3 13
1 A4 11
```

How can I combine the two queries to get a result like "Expected Output" above?

Comment: A SQL query with no `order by` -- such as your first one -- returns results in an *arbitrary order*.  It may look like what you want, but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.b_id = b.id
ORDER BY b.name, a.name;
```

That said, for your sample in the question, this seems to work:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
order by a.b_id, a.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> output rows in TableA ...

So you might wish to consider using a LEFT JOIN to ensure you don't lose any rows in TableA:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.b_id = b.id
ORDER BY b.name, a.name;
```